# Grant CloudWatch Full Access to IAM role for specific namespace

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch

Could not find this in the documentation anywhere — let's say I want to allow an IAM role to have full CloudWatch access but only for a single namespace of my choosing.

Is this possible?